# How to check if an attribute has default value defined in __init__

Tags: python

How can I check if an attribute of an object has been set by the user or not? Currently, I have a class

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = 'baz'
```

Later I would like to check if the user set the value of `bar` or not, i.e. with something like

```
my_foo = foo()
my_foo.bar = 'mybaz'
```

so I would like to know if the second line above has been called or not (to throw a warning if it has not). I have two solutions, but I don't like either of them:

1. Check if `my_foo.bar` is equal to the default value. But it could be that the user sets `my_foo.bar` to the same value and then I don't want to throw a warning.
2. Don't set the default value in `__init__`, but only when it is used. Then it can be checked with `getattr()` and set with `setattr()`.

I'm sure there is an elegant pythonic way to do it that I haven't thought of.

Comment: Would preventing direct assignment to such attributes be enough? I.e. throwing an exception as soon as the assignment is made? Please explain how you'd like to check

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `@property` decorator to construct getters and setters, and the make the setter tell you when a user changes the attribute, example below

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self._x_was_modified = False
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x_was_modified = True
        self._x = value

foo = Foo()
print('x was modified by user: {}'.format(foo._x_was_modified))
foo.x = 42
print('x was modified by user: {}'.format(foo._x_was_modified))
```

This will output:

```
x was modified by user: False
x was modified by user: True
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that again involves using a `flag` is done by playing around with the `__setattr__` method:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._altered = -1
        self.bar = 'baz'

    def __setattr__(self, attrname, val):
        if attrname is 'bar':
            self._altered += 1
        super.__setattr__(self, attrname, val)
        # if you heard super is evil and you feel 
        # funny using it in your code instead use:
        # object.__setattr__(self, attrname, val)
```

If somebody *re-sets* this variable the value of `self._altered` will be positive and as a result evaluate to `True` (remember, first access is made in `__init__` during initialization and increments `_altered` once).

After this you can make a nice intuitive check of the form:

```
f = foo()
f.bar = "booz"  # now f._altered == 1

if f._altered: raise MyAlcoholicException
```

and be done. Just another way of doing practically the same exact thing.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super super is a method and should be called as such, also, the solution is cumbersome and not advisable for production use IMO.

Comment: The OP is using new style classes as used in `Py3` so I used `super` in that way, additionally I provided the more general delegation to `object`. If it is cumbersome or not is debatable and the comments are not the place for this debate. Either way no harm in providing an alternate solution. I accept your downvote either way :)